# html/css: svg or png cant replicate masking even with simple copy paste example

Tags: css, svg, mask

Was originally trying to get a .svg to mask a div. After spending a few hours trying to apply related examples I couldn't get it working.

Have been gradually working back to the most basic example of masking, just to get something going, but cant seem to display it as indicated in the example. I am quite certain that I have replicated it exactly as shown here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_masking.asp however there is no masking with the files I have outputted (have included an overview of my file [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92YV5.jpg)). Used chrome (version 101), Microsoft edge, and firefox with the same result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.mask1 {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(w3logo.png);
  mask-image: url(w3logo.png);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The mask-image Property</h1>

<h3>An image with a mask layer image:</h3>
<div class="mask1">
<img src="img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
</div>

<h3>Original image:</h3>
<img src="img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">

</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can give me an indication of what is happening with the above example, that would be really handy. Also if the next step of masking a div (not just an image) with a svg (ideally within the css) that would be phenominal.

The ideal workflow I would be looking for would be to output a .svg mask and be able to apply that to a div and anything in it.

Comment: you need to add the html and CSS you have tried so someone can help you here.

Comment: Thanks Crystal. Will edit my original post right now to include the code.